# Music is not playing in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

i am creating an app i store a file in raw folder with name
alarm_tone.mp3

i am saving it in one

```
 SharedPreferences shared=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shared.edit();
     editor.putString("music_uri", "android.resource://" + "org.riteshmapsapplicationdemo/" + R.raw.alarm_tone);
    editor.commit();
```

in other activity i am playing this tone using code segment

```
player=new MediaPlayer();
try {
    player.setDataSource(pref.getString("music_uri", null));
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it is showing 
Media.prepare() failed
java.io.IOException

Comment: where does `pref` come from? In the first snipped you called the SharedPreferences object `shared`, are you sure that you are getting the correct SharedPreferences when you instantiate `pref`? Can you post the code where you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse Uri:

```
player.setDataSource(Uri.parse(pref.getString("music_uri", null)));
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code as:

```
 SharedPreferences shared=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shared.edit();
     editor.putString("music_uri", "android.resource://" +
                          this.getPackageName() + "/raw/alarm_tone");
    editor.commit();
```

change playing code segment

```
player=new MediaPlayer();
try {
   SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
   String struri=pref.getString("music_uri", null);
  if(struri !=null){
      Uri mUri = Uri.parse(struri);
         player.setDataSource(mUri);
         player.prepare();
         player.start();
   }
  //your code here...
```